# A better paste command

Tags: text-processing, columns, paste

I have the following two files ( I padded the lines with dots so every line in a file is the same width and made file1 all caps to make it more clear).

```
contents of file1:

ETIAM......
SED........
MAECENAS...
DONEC......
SUSPENDISSE

contents of file2

Lorem....
Proin....
Nunc.....
Quisque..
Aenean...
Nam......
Vivamus..
Curabitur
Nullam...
```

Notice that file2 is longer than file1.

When I run this command:

```
paste file1 file2
```

I get this output

```
ETIAM...... Lorem....
SED........ Proin....
MAECENAS... Nunc.....
DONEC...... Quisque..
SUSPENDISSE Aenean...
    Nam......
    Vivamus..
    Curabitur
    Nullam...
```

**What can I do for the output to be as follows ?**

```
ETIAM...... Lorem....
SED........ Proin....
MAECENAS... Nunc.....
DONEC...... Quisque..
SUSPENDISSE Aenean...
            Nam......
            Vivamus..
            Curabitur
            Nullam...
```

I tried

```
paste file1 file2 | column -t
```

but it does this:

```
ETIAM......  Lorem....
SED........  Proin....
MAECENAS...  Nunc.....
DONEC......  Quisque..
SUSPENDISSE  Aenean...
Nam......
Vivamus..
Curabitur
Nullam...
```

non as ugly as the original output but wrong column-wise anyway.

Comment: `paste` is using tabs in front of the lines from second file.  You may have to use a postprocessor to align the columns appropriately.

Comment: `paste file1 file2 | column -tn` ?

Comment: does file1 always have fixed size columns?

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Yes, it does.

Comment: `paste file[12] | column -s $'\t' -t -o ' '` or have I missed something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any tab characters in your files,

```
paste file1 file2 | expand -t 13
```

with the arg to `-t` suitably chosen to cover the desired max line width in file1.

OP has added a more flexible  solution:

I did this so it works without the magic number 13:

```
paste file1 file2 | expand -t $(( $(wc -L <file1) + 2 ))
```

It's not easy to type but can be used in a script.

Comment: nice! I didn't know about expand before I read your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I thought awk might do it nicely, so I googled "awk reading input from two files" and found [an article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files) to use as a starting point.

First is the condensed version, then fully commented below that.  This took a more than a few minutes to work out.  I'd be glad of some refinements from smarter folks.

```
awk '{if(length($0)>max)max=length($0)}
FNR==NR{s1[FNR]=$0;next}{s2[FNR]=$0}
END { format = "%-" max "s\t%-" max "s\n";
  numlines=(NR-FNR)>FNR?NR-FNR:FNR;
  for (i=1; i<=numlines; i++) { printf format, s1[i]?s1[i]:"", s2[i]?s2[i]:"" }
}' file1 file2
```

And here is the fully documented version of the above.

```
# 2013-11-05 mike@diehn.net
# Invoke thus:
#   awk -f this_file file1 file2
# The result is what you asked for and the columns will be
# determined by input file order.
#----------------------------------------------------------
# No matter which file we're reading,
# keep track of max line length for use
# in the printf format.
#
{ if ( length($0) > max ) max=length($0) }

# FNR is record number in current file
# NR is record number over all
# while they are equal, we're reading the first file
#   and we load the strings into array "s1"
#   and then go to the "next" line in the file we're reading.
FNR==NR { s1[FNR]=$0; next }

# and when they aren't, we're reading the
#   second file and we put the strings into
#   array s2
{s2[FNR]=$0}

# At the end, after all lines from both files have
# been read,
END {
  # use the max line length to create a printf format
  # the right widths
  format = "%-" max "s\t%-" max "s\n"
  # and figure the number of array elements we need
  # to cycle through in a for loop.
  numlines=(NR-FNR)>FNR?NR-FNR:FNR;
  for (i=1; i<=numlines; i++) {
     printf format, s1[i]?s1[i]:"", s2[i]?s2[i]:""
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that does work with arbitrary input (i.e. with lines that may contain tabs). I don't think this could be significantly  refined/improved.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian and derivatives, `column` has a `-n` *nomerge* option that allows column to do the right thing with empty fields. Internally, `column` uses the `wcstok(wcs, delim, ptr)` function, which splits a wide character string into tokens delimited by the wide characters in the `delim` argument.

`wcstok` starts by skipping wide characters in `delim`, before recognizing the token. The `-n` option uses an algorythm that doesn't skip initial wide-characters in `delim`.

Unfortunately, this isn't very portable: `-n` is Debian-specific, and `column` is not in POSIX, it's apparently a BSD thing.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very good solution but I was able to do it using

```
paste file1 file2 | sed 's/^TAB/&&/'
```

where TAB is replaced with the tab character.

Comment: What is the role of `&&` in the sed command?

Comment: A single `&` puts what is being searched for (a tab in this case).  This command simply replaces the tab at the beginning with two tabs.

Comment: I had to change `TAB` to `\t` to make this work in zsh on Ubuntu debian. And it does only work if file1 has less than 15 chars

Answer (score 2):

Taking out the dots that you used for padding:

file1:

```
ETIAM
SED
MAECENAS
DONEC
SUSPENDISSE
```

file2:

```
Lorem
Proin
Nunc
Quisque
Aenean
Nam
Vivamus
Curabitur
Nullam
```

Try this:

```
$ ( echo ".TS"; echo "l l."; paste file1 file2; echo ".TE" ) | tbl | nroff | more
```

And you will get:

```
ETIAM         Lorem
SED           Proin
MAECENAS      Nunc
DONEC         Quisque
SUSPENDISSE   Aenean
              Nam
              Vivamus
              Curabitur
              Nullam
```

Comment: This, like the other solutions using `paste` will fail to print the proper output if there are any lines containing tabs. +1 for being different though

Comment: +1. Would you please explain how the solution works?

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution that should be fairly portable, and should work for an arbitrary number of input files:

```
# Invoke thus:
#   awk -F\\t -f this_file file1 file2

# every time we read a new file, FNR goes to 1

FNR==1 {
    curfile++                       # current file
}

# read all files and save all the info we'll need
{
    column[curfile,FNR]=$0          # save current line
    nlines[curfile]++               # number of lines in current file
    if (length > len[curfile])
            len[curfile] = length   # max line length in current file
}

# finally, show the lines from all files side by side, as a table
END {
    # iterate through lines until there are no more lines in any file
    for (line = 1; !end; line++) {
            $0 = _
            end = 1

            # iterate through all files, we cannot use
            #   for (file in nlines) because arrays are unordered
            for (file=1; file <= curfile; file++) {
                    # columnate corresponding line from each file
                    $0 = $0 sprintf("%*s" FS, len[file], column[file,line])
                    # at least some file had a corresponding line
                    if (nlines[file] >= line)
                            end = 0
            }

            # don't print a trailing empty line
            if (!end)
                    print
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this on file1 and file2? I called the script `paste-awk` and tried `paste file1 file2|paste-awk` and I tried `awk paste-awk file1 file2` but none worked.

Comment: I get `awk: Line:1: (FILENAME=file1 FNR=1) Fatal: Division by zero`

Comment: @rubo77: `awk -f paste-awk file1 file2` should work, at least for GNU awk and mawk.

Comment: This works, although it is slightly different from `paste` there is less space between the two rows. And if the input file has not all rows same length, it will result in an align-right row

Comment: @rubo77: the field separator can be set with `-F\\t`